# Promises - how to handle known errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, async-await, try-catch

I understand how promises work but I don't quite get what the best/intended way to handle known errors is ... how they are meant to be handled.

Example:
Let's say function `fetch('/api/login')` returns a promise that (for simplicity) either resolves with `{status: 200}` or `{status: 500}` or `{status: 401}` (which means the credentials were incorrect)

My idea how to handle the different cases was something like:

```
const login = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/login')
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return Promise.resolve()
    } else if (res.status === 401) {
      return Promise.reject('INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS') // throw should work here too
    } else {
      throw new Error('Request failed')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      console.error('Something really bad happened', e)
      return Promise.reject() // discard the error
    } else {
      throw e // it's a known error, pass it down
    }
  }
}

// Somewhere inside a LoginForm component
try {
  await login()
  redirectSomewhere() // Successful login
} catch (e) {
  if (e === 'INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS') {
    showIncorrectCredentialsText()
  }
  // ignore other errors
}
```

Then I tried to implement it with bluebird and got this warning: `a promise was rejected with a non-error` and according to [their explanation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error), promises should only reject with `Error` objects. Why ? Because of debug. But this `INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS` error is not some unknown error that needs to be debugged. I don't even think it's an error at all, the promise rejects just because `login` failed, for whatever reason. Does that mean that for every known error I want to handle myself, the promise should resolve with `{error: 'ERROR_CODE'}` ? If so, what is the meaning of `catch`ing individual errors, then ? If every error is "meant to be debugged" ...

I know i can just create my own `IncorrectCredentialsError` but I don't see the benefits there if I don't really care about some stacktrace ...

I am  a little bit confused here, so please could anyone give me a quick introduction what proper error handling should look like ? :)

Comment: Why not just reject with `new Error("INCORRECT CREDENTIALS")` then?

Comment: I think it's the same as an own `IncorrectCredentialsError`, isn't it ? What would the benefits be apart from keeping bluebird silent ? My goal is not to keep it silent but to understand why the warning is there in the first place ...

Comment: I'm not very fluent yet in the whole async/await syntax, but can't you just return the login details if 200 and an error object for the error cases because the async/await syntax will wrap the return inside a promise to begin with. If you can use async/await syntax, I would just remove bluebird from the project since native promises are a requirement for async/await to work.

Comment: And the warning is there because the bluebird API expects you to return an error ( or a different object with a stack and a message property ) since this is fed into their error handling code which expects those two properties to exist. That's just the way Bluebird has implemented promises.

Comment: Why shouldn't async/await work with bluebird ? Could you give me a reference ? BTW I may rewrite the code to use pure Promises without async/await if it helps ...

Comment: Async/await is just syntax sugar for native promises. Bluebird has its own promise implementation. You can perfectly use them side-by-side. But imho, chose one or the other so the code stays more clean and you don't have to deal with cases like these, where the native promises act differently than bluebirds promises and you have to think about it every time: is this a bluebird promise I have to reject with an error or is this a native promise I can reject with anything. Have a look at this for other peoples opinions when to use which: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1434

Comment: So rejecting with something else then an `Error` object is perfectly fine with native Promises ? Doesn't seem to be the case, according to the first sentence of  bluebird explanation: `Due to a historic mistake in JavaScript, the throw statement is allowed to be used with any value, not just errors`. Again, my goal is not to find a workaround but to understand how it is meant to be done :)

Comment: What does the throw statement have to do with how native promises work? You can `Promise.reject()` anything with native promises, as the promise spec calls for. It's only the bluebird implementation where you're forced to use an error object, hence bluebird does not follow the Promises/A+ specification 100%. Try it yourself in chrome: `Promise.reject('something').catch(e => console.error(e));`.

Comment: Notice that `return Promise.reject() // discard the error` would *really* discard the stack trace, which you probably don't want there.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're using async/await syntax, but with the bluebird implementation of `Promise`. So you're forced to use error objects to reject promises and all other bluebird-style things described inside the bluebird API.

In your situation, I would choose between the following three options:

1) Use bluebird for everything, dropping the async/await syntax and using bluebird error handling by rejecting with error objects and all the other things bluebird offers.

2) Use the async/await syntax with try/catch:

```
// API
const HTTP_ERRORS = {
    "404": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "500": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
};
const login = async () => {
    const response = await fetch( '/login' );
    const status = response.status;
    if ( !status ) throw new Error( "INVALID RESPONSE" );
    else if ( status === 200 ) return JSON.parse( response.responseText );
    else return HTTP_ERRORS[ JSON.stringify( status ) ]; // or throw new Error( HTTP_ERRORS[ JSON.stringify( status )]); 
};
// workflow
try {
    const profile = await login();
}
catch( error ) {
    console.error( error );
}
```

3) Use native promises directly:

```
// API
const HTTP_ERRORS = {
    "404": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "500": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
};
const login = () => fetch( '/login' )
    .then( response => {
        const status = response.status;
        if ( !status ) throw new Error( "INVALID RESPONSE" );
        else if ( status === 200 ) return JSON.parse( response.responseText );
        else throw new Error( HTTP_ERRORS[ JSON.stringify( status )]);
    });
// workflow
login()
    .then( profile => { console.log( 'ok' ); })
    .catch( error => console.error( error ));
```

Either solution is fine, as long as you are consistent.
In my humble opinion, combining all these combinations in one project at random will just confuse the next person debugging your code.